# jquery target text nodes that begin with (string1) and end with (string2)

Tags: javascript, jquery, replace

I'd like to be able to target (and then remove) this string of text:

```
[UPLOAD]any-possible_FILEname.ANY[/UPLOAD]
```

HTML:

```js
var filenameRegex = new RegExp("\w\d\.");
$('.posts').contents().filter(':contains([UPLOAD])').filter(':contains([/UPLOAD])').filter(function() {
  return filenameRegex.test($(this).text());
  console.log('yep');
}).remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="posts">
        This is a forum post with lots of blabbing in it.

        [UPLOAD]this-is-a-random-unknown-filename.jpg[/UPLOAD] 

        (Note the above always begins with [UPLOAD] and ends 
        with [/UPLOAD]. Also note that between these 'tags' 
        is 1 filename of some kind, such as an image or audio
        or text file)
</span>
```

Thanks, much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var filenameRegex = /\[UPLOAD][\w\.\-]+\[\/UPLOAD]/gi;
$('.posts').filter(':contains([UPLOAD]):contains([/UPLOAD])').filter(function(i,e) {
  return filenameRegex.test($(e).text());
}).each(function(i,e){ 
  $(e).text($(e).text().replace(filenameRegex,''));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="posts">
        This is a forum post with lots of blabbing in it.

        [UPLOAD]this-is-a-random-unknown-filename.jpg[/UPLOAD] 

        (Note the above always begins with [UPLOAD] and ends 
        with [/UPLOAD]. Also note that between these 'tags' 
        is 1 filename of some kind, such as an image or audio
        or text file)
</span>
```

Comment: Grrr.. I accepted the answer too quickly. It works, but, it removes the whole post rather than just the text node string.

Comment: You want what part removed? The whole text or just the [UPLOAD]...[/UPLOAD] part?

Comment: OK it works now! (I had to remove the second ';' at the end of it though, i.e., });; <-- extra thingy. Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

The regex you need is:

```
/\[UPLOAD\](.*)\[\/UPLOAD\]/gi
```

So your code should be like:

```
var filenameRegex = new RegExp("/\[UPLOAD\](.*)\[\/UPLOAD\]/gi"); 
$('.posts').contents().filter(':contains([UPLOAD])').filter(':contains([/UPLOAD])').filter(function(){
    return filenameRegex.test($(this).text()); 
    console.log('yep');
}).remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Not a regular expression, but this seems to do the trick:

```
var text = 'hello [UPLOAD]very[/UPLOAD] [UPLOAD]cruel[/UPLOAD] world';
var start = '[UPLOAD]';
var end = '[/UPLOAD]';

var index = text.indexOf(start);
while (index > -1)
{
    var end_index = text.indexOf(end);
    var removed_text = text.substring(index, end_index + end.length));
    text = text.substring(0, index) + text.substring(end_index + end.length);
    index = text.indexOf(start);
}
```